# Живой поиск - глюк при работе с планшета

Tags: jquery

Нашел в сети вот такой простенький "живой поиск", суть проста, есть input, в него начинаем вводить название, если похожее есть в базе, то скрипт предлагает возможные варианты, при выборе одного из них, выбор подставляется в input, а варианты скрываются. Все отлично и работает, но есть нюанс!)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пользоваться с планшета, то при клике на вариант он сначала подставляет выбор в input, а скрывает выпадающий список только после повторного клика по выбранному варианту.

Как это исправить? Спасибо!!

```js
$(function() {

  //Живой поиск
  $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "search_car.php", //Путь к обработчику
        data: {
          'referal': this.value
        },
        response: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
          $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
        }
      })
    }
  })

  $(".search_result").hover(function() {
    $(".who").blur(); //Убираем фокус с input
  })

  //При выборе результата поиска, прячем список и заносим выбранный результат в input
  $(".search_result").on("click", "li", function() {
    s_user = $(this).text();
    $(".who").val(s_user);
    $(".search_result").fadeOut();
  })


  $(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документу
    var div = $(".search_result"); // тут указываем ID элемента
    if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      &&
      div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
      div.hide(); // скрываем его
    }
  });


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size='5' name="referal" value="" class="who" id='css-input' autocomplete="off">
<ul class="search_result"></ul>
```

Comment: А можно чуть больше информации? Например, почему используется так много слушателей для инпута - сразу 4? Зачем при ховере убирать фокус с инпута? Если вставить алерты на коллбек `fadeOut()` и за пределами самого первого `if()`, но внутри обработчика клика, что будет при вводе с планшета?

Comment: я не совсем понял о каких слушателях идет речь :\
фокус убираем, чтобы повторного выпадания списка не происходило.
если вынести fadeOut из if() то работать перестает (